# Protractor .getAttribute('href') not working

Tags: javascript, protractor, gulp-protractor

**Goal**: test that the 'href' value of first element in my 'div' equals to 'myLink'.

**Html**:

```
<div id="myId">
    <a href="myLink"/>
</div>
```

**Protractor code**:

```
var elems = element.all(by.id('myId'));
elems.first().getAttribute('href').then(function(attr) {
    expect(attr).toEqual('myLink');
});
```

**Error message**: "Expected null to equal 'myLink'."

**Question**: What is wrong in this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to get the href attribute from the div element.But the div element does'nt have href attribute,so protractors gives you null as output. Try the below code.

```
var elems = element.all(by.css('#myId a'));
   elems.first().getAttribute('href').then(function(attr) {
       expect(attr).toEqual('myLink');
   });
```

Comment: For coding reasons, I have to use 'elems ' to retrieve the <a> tag. I thought 'elems' was an array of all elements inside 'div' so that elems.first() would return the '<a>' element...

Comment: But 'elems' is just a list of all the '<div id="myId">' in the page. I understand my mistake now

Answer (score 0):

To add to the existing answer. *You don't have to resolve the promise to make the expectation*. `expect()` is patched to understand promises:

```
var elems = element.all(by.css('#myId a'));
expect(elems.first().getAttribute('href')).toEqual('myLink');
```